# necessary and sufficient conditions for a function to "have a tangent vector at almost all points"

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, curves

If I have a nice curve $z(t)$ and a reparametrization $t(s)$, what does it mean for $z(t(s))$ to have a tangent vector at all s, (or more specifically, at almost all s)

Comment: I'm a little confused by the difference between this question's title and its body.  Are you looking for necessary and sufficient conditions on $z$ and $t$ to justify the assertion that $z\circ t$ has a well defined tangent for (almost) all $s$, or are you looking for a detailed description of the (say) geometric interpretation of there being a tangent vector:  "What does it mean for $z(t(s))$ to have a tangent vector at all $s$?"